# Why BackKeyPress can not execute in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I found a weird thing in WP7.When the virtual keyboard display in the page,the page's BackKeyPress event can't execute. Can anybody know why?

Answer (score 3):

When the virtual keyboard display in the page, you Press the Back Device Button. Firstly the virtual keyboard will disappear. And if you press the Back Device Button again the BackKeyPress will fire.